# Best practice for writing views in Django (how to comment params, transferring request out of view and what about messages)

Tags: django, django-views

**service.py**

```
def add_goods_to_cart(goods_id, user, addend):
    goods = Goods.objects.filter(pk=goods_id).first()

    if goods:

        the_goods_already_in_cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user, goods=goods, order=None).first()

        if the_goods_already_in_cart:
            the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity = (the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity + addend)

            if the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity == 0:
                the_goods_already_in_cart.delete()
            else:
                the_goods_already_in_cart.save()

        else:
            Cart.objects.create(user=user, goods=goods, quantity=1)
        status = 200
    else:
        status = 400

    return status
```

**views.py**

```
class AddToCart(LoginRequiredMixin,
                View):
    def post(self, request):
        goods_id = request.POST.get('goods_id')
        addend = int(request.POST.get('addend'))

        assert (addend == 1 or addend == -1)

        status = add_goods_to_cart(goods_id, request.user, addend)
        if status == 200:
            act = "added to cart" if addend > 0 else "removed from cart"
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Goods "{}" {}.'.format(goods.name, act))
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Wrong goods id", status=status)
```

What troubles me:

1. Can I transmit request from views.py to service.py? A view is
   something that operates on request. In my logic, it is reasonable
   not to transmit request out of view. Receive data from request,
   transmit the data to the service.
2. What will create the message? In my logic, it is the responsibility
   of the view. But the view doesn't know anything about the name of
   the goods. Look here: this code will not work just because there is
   no name of the goods for the message.

Well, anyway, the architecture of this code stinks. Maybe I should return from the service not the status code, but the name of the added goods?

How can I refactor this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to return status code in your service.py to understand what happened in it, there is an also simpler way to return both good's name and a sign of what has happened in service.py by only returning good's name if it existed and None if it not existed. so you can handle status code in your view and also you have the name of that good:

```
goods = Goods.objects.filter(pk=goods_id).first()

if goods:
    the_goods_already_in_cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user, goods=goods, order=None).first()

    if the_goods_already_in_cart:
        the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity = (the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity + addend)
    
        if the_goods_already_in_cart.quantity == 0:
            the_goods_already_in_cart.delete()
        else:
            the_goods_already_in_cart.save()
    
    else:
        Cart.objects.create(user=user, goods=goods, quantity=1)
    
    return goods.name # Return the name of the added goods

return None # This shows that goods were not found
```

Comment: It looks like this answer is missing some indentation. Please repair it when you can.

Comment: I have attempted to add some indentation to this. Please check it. I can see you are still signing in.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stackoverflow I don't know what you mean by checking.
Should I edit anything?

Comment: The formatting of the code in your answer was wrong, and it would not have worked. I have attempted to repair it. But, since you wrote it, it would be good if you would ensure that it is now correct. If it is not correct, then yes, it would need to be edited.